# PHP mysqli query output wrong

Tags: php, mysqli

THIS IS SOLVED (EDIT ON THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE)

I got a problem with the output off the query in the foreach statement. For some reason the dump of the variables give NULL NULL NULL etc instead of the right output out of table Items. does anyone know what causes this ?

```
        <?php
        $offers_array = array();

        $query = "select trade_offer.*, gebruikers.naam, gebruikers.image_url from trade_offer join gebruikers on gebruikers.id = trade_offer.sender_id where receiver_id = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt-> bind_param('i', $gebruiker->id); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $offers_array[] = $row; 
        }

        foreach($offers_array as $offer){
        $query_fetch = "select * from items where id in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query_fetch);
        $stmt-> bind_param('iiiiiiii', $offer['receiver_gets_1'], $offer['receiver_gets_2'], $offer['receiver_gets_3'], $offer['receiver_gets_4'], $offer['sender_gets_1'], $offer['sender_gets_2'], $offer['sender_gets_3'], $offer['sender_gets_4']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $id = $col1;
        $naam = $col2;
        $prijs = $col3;
        $image = $col4;

        echo $id;
        echo $naam;
        echo $prijs;
        echo $image;
    }   
}?>
```

Dump of $offer:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 8
    [receiver_id] => 2
    [sender_id] => 3
    [receiver_gets_1] => 10
    [receiver_gets_2] => 15
    [receiver_gets_3] => 18
    [receiver_gets_4] => 13
    [sender_gets_1] => 19
    [sender_gets_2] => 14
    [sender_gets_3] => 17
    [sender_gets_4] => 9
    [accepted] => 
    [naam] => John
    [image_url] => http://www.example.com/img.jpg
)
```

Content of items table:

```
id   naam  prijs  image_url
1    item1  2.00  example.com
2    item2  2.00  example.com
3    item3  2.00  example.com
4    item4  2.00  example.com
5    item5  2.00  example.com
6    item6  2.00  example.com
etc.
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I edited my code to the answer of Kim Alexander and now the following error occurs:
 `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in ......\tradeoffers.php on line 31`

Line 31:

`$stmt-> bind_param('iiiiiiii', $offer['receiver_gets_1'], $offer['receiver_gets_2'], $offer['receiver_gets_3'], $offer['receiver_gets_4'], $offer['sender_gets_1'], $offer['sender_gets_2'], $offer['sender_gets_3'], $offer['sender_gets_4']);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant not:

```
 $result = $stmt->get_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $id = $col1;
        $naam = $col2;
```

but

```
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $id = $col1;
        $naam = $col2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only now i get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in ....\tradeoffers.php on line 31` And this is line 31 in my file: `$stmt-> bind_param('iiiiiiii', $offer['receiver_gets_1'], $offer['receiver_gets_2'], $offer['receiver_gets_3'], $offer['receiver_gets_4'], $offer['sender_gets_1'], $offer['sender_gets_2'], $offer['sender_gets_3'], $offer['sender_gets_4']);`